# Calling multiple commands in SQLite3 from Command Prompt

Tags: batch-file, sqlite

I want to be able to make a batchfile that will loop through every file in a directory and import it inside SQlite3. The problem I have is that SQlite3 does not accept multiple commands from command prompt/batch, only 1 command.

What I have tried is :

```
 for %%f in (./tmp/*.csv) do (
     echo %%f
     sqlite3 database.db ".separator '|'" ".import './tmp/%%f' Dirs"
 )
```

And I get a too many options error, as it is only expecting a single command, while I need more than 1.

I also cannot write a second text file to be called by sqlite3 as the file being imported will change for every iteration.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [option](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sqlite3) `-separator` to set the separator (whose default already is `|`).

If you'd really need to execute multiple commands, you could write them to a file and `.read` that, or `echo` all of them and pipe them into `sqlite3`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize the separator option.